# Python/Scrapy Import Error: Can not import name

Tags: python, import, scrapy

Im new to Python/Scrapy.  using python2.7

My error:

```
line 5 in module  from scrapy.item import wikispiderItem
Import Error: Can not import name wikispiderItem
```

Folder/File Structure

```
C:\wikispider\wikispider

    -_init_.py
    -items.py
    -pipelines.py
    -settings.py
          -_init_.py
          -wikiSpider.py
```

**items.py code**

from scrapy.items import Item, Field, Link

```
class wikispiderItem(scrapy.items):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    hxs = Field()
    heading = Field()
    link = Field()
```

**wikispider.py code**

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.item import wikispiderItem

class wikiSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "wikiSpider"
    allowed_domains = ['wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics']

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="mw-body"]//a/@href'))),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor( allow=("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/",)),callback='parse_item'),
        )
    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs =HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        print hxs.select('//h1[@class="firstHeading"]/span/text()').extract()
        headng = hxs.select('//h1[@class="firstHeading"]/span/text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from wikispider.items import wikispiderItem`

Your `items.py` should be:

```
import scrapy


class wikispiderItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    hxs = scrapy.Field()
    heading = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from scrapy.item import wikispiderItem
```

The above line in `wikispider.py` should be...

```
from wikispider.items import wikispiderItem
```